# Lucene.NET TextField not being indexed

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Using .NET 6.0 and Lucene.NET-4.8.0-beta00016 from NuGet

I am having an issue implementing the [quickstart example](https://lucenenet.apache.org/quick-start/tutorial.html) from the website. When using TextField in a document, the field is not indexed. The search later in the BuildIndex method retrieves no results. If TextField is changed to StringField, the example works and the search returns a valid result.

Why does StringField work and TextField doesn't? I read that StringField is not analyzed but TextField is, so perhaps it's something to do with the StandardAnalyzer?

```
public class LuceneFullTextSearchService {

private readonly IndexWriter _writer;
private readonly Analyzer _standardAnalyzer;

public LuceneFullTextSearchService(string indexName)
{
    // Compatibility version
    const LuceneVersion luceneVersion = LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48;
    string indexPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, indexName);
    Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.Open(indexPath);

    // Create an analyzer to process the text 
    _standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion);

    // Create an index writer
    IndexWriterConfig indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(luceneVersion, _standardAnalyzer)
    {
        OpenMode = OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND,
    };
    _writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, indexConfig);
}

public void BuildIndex(string searchPath)
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    
    TextField docText = new TextField("title", "Apache", Field.Store.YES); 
    doc.Add(docText);
    
    _writer.AddDocument(doc);

    //Flush and commit the index data to the directory
    _writer.Commit();
    
    // Parse the user's query text
    Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("title", "Apache"));
    
    // Search
    using DirectoryReader reader = _writer.GetReader(applyAllDeletes: true);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, n: 2);

    // Show results
    Document resultDoc = searcher.Doc(topDocs.ScoreDocs[0].Doc);
    string title = resultDoc.Get("title");
}
}
```

Comment: The `BuildIndex` method makes no logical sense. Building an index, modifying (adding/deleting records), and searching are typically 3 different functions that are done at different times. See [LuceneNetDemo](https://github.com/NightOwl888/LuceneNetDemo/blob/master/LuceneNetDemo/GitHubIndex.cs) for an example that separates building the index from search. If you need to  modify the index while searching is occurring on other threads, you would call `writer.GetReader(applyAllDeletes: true/false)` in search using the same instance of writer that modifies the index in parallel.

Comment: @NightOwl888 This is a stripped down example of a class which normally implements these things at separate functions. I wanted to be sure I knew where the problem was exactly and the "loading files from a directory and creating documents from them" and separating the index/search code was unnecessary to ask this question.

Comment: @andrewJames I want to tokenize a string and search it by word/phrase. I was under the impression that TextField was the way to do this. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StandardAnalyzer`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/analysis-common/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.html) includes a [`LowerCaseFilter`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/analysis-common/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Core.LowerCaseFilter.html), so your text is stored in the index as lower-case.

However, when you build your query, the text you use is "Apache" rather than "apache", so it doesn't produce any hits.

```
// Parse the user's query text
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("title", "Apache"));
```

### Option 1

Lowercase your search term.

```
// Parse the user's query text
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("title", "Apache".ToLowerInvariant()));
```

### Option 2

Use a [`QueryParser`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/queryparser/overview.html) with the *same* analyzer you use to build the index.

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(luceneVersion, "title", _standardAnalyzer);
Query query = parser.Parse("Apache");
```

The [`Lucene.Net.QueryParser` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.QueryParser) contains several implementations (the above example uses the `Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.Classic.QueryParser`).

Comment: This is definitely the problem. I was using a QueryParser originally when I was on 3.0.8 but when I upgraded, it stopped being able to find the type so I went to a manually built query and completely forgot about case sensitivity. I'll use the ToLowerInvariant() option for now until I can figure out where QueryParser is.   

This is my first question on StackOverflow and it was answered in less than a day so I am really pleased. Thank you for your time in figuring this out.